# What am I doing wrong when rotating the picture by 90 degrees

Tags: java, arrays, image, ppm

I'm absolutely stumped with this problem. So here's my logic with rotating an array by 90 degrees:

Example:

```
1 2 3 4 5.....   ^
2 6 8 7 4.....   | 
6 4 9 8 0.....   | .....THEN.....  ------>
8 3 0 5 9.....   |
```

So If I want to rotate it by 90 degrees, what I want is to read the array from the bottomost row going up, then add a width to the right. So the array will be

```
8 6 2 1
3 4 6 2 
0 9 8 3
5 8 7 4
9 0 4 5
```

Now I'm applying this logic to my array of pixels and rotate the picture by 90 degrees

Here's my code for my method in Java for it:

```
public void rotate90(){

    Pixel[][] rotated = new Pixel[Iwidth][Iheight];

    int Ch = Iheight-1, Cw = 0;

    while (Cw < Iwidth){
        while (Ch > -1){
            rotated[Cw][Iheight - Ch - 1] = new Pixel(Image[Ch][Cw].getRed(), Image[Ch][Cw].getGreen(), Image[Ch][Cw].getBlue());
            Ch--;
        }
        Cw++;
        Ch = Iheight-1;
    }

    Image = rotated;


    int temp = Iheight;
    Iheight = Iwidth;
    Iwidth = temp;
}
```

When I call the method, it makes the picture garbled, but the width and height of the picture is switched/swapped.

But here's when it gets me, If I try to call the method TWICE, then the picture will be rotated properly 180 degrees

and if I try to call the methor FOUR times, the the picture will be the sa,e as it is.

Can anyone shed some light on what am I missing or doing wrong?

---

I have found the problem, I can't answer my own question so here's the problem with my code:

Instead of putting

```
imageWriter.println(Iwidth + " " + Iheight);
```

I have a

```
imageWriter.println(Iheight + " " + Iwidth);
```

In my writer method Silly me -***_*__*_***-

Thanks for @Marcelo and @rolfl on trying to help. Found the problem.

My code was right all the time, I have a silly 1 liner code that messed me up

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong. In what way is the picture garbled? Are you sure the problem isn't with the display code?

Comment: That's what I thought too. But when I try to call rotate90 twice, it will produce a correct 180 degree rotation. Same with calling it 4 times, it will produce the same original image

Comment: I can't say for sure, but there is a pattern, I can't just describe it to words. Here's an example of the pictures. [Original](http://puu.sh/59I9w.jpg) vs [Garbled Image](http://puu.sh/59Ido.png)

Comment: When I try to call rotate90() Twice, then it produces [a correct 180 degree rotation](http://puu.sh/59IiE.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, Marcelo beat me to it, but my program actually runs....

First, either implement a `clone()` method, or create a new constructor for `Pixel` which takes an existing Pixel to 'copy'.

This rotation is simpler to process as a function of a position.... I have it working here using String values instead of pixels

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int width = 5, height = 3;
    String[][] values = new String[height][width];
    for (int c = 0; c < width; c++) {
        for (int r = 0; r < height; r++) {
            values[r][c] = String.format("%3d", r * width + c);
        }
    }

    for (String[] row : values) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }

    System.out.println();

    int nheight = width;
    int nwidth = height;

    String[][] rotate = new String[nheight][nwidth];
    for (int c = 0; c < nwidth; c++) {
        for (int r = 0; r < nheight; r++) {
            rotate[r][c] = values[height - 1 - c][r];
        }
    }

    for (String[] row : rotate) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }
}
```

It produces the output

```
[  0,   1,   2,   3,   4]
[  5,   6,   7,   8,   9]
[ 10,  11,  12,  13,  14]

[ 10,   5,   0]
[ 11,   6,   1]
[ 12,   7,   2]
[ 13,   8,   3]
[ 14,   9,   4]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for what you need:

```
public void rotate90() {
    Pixel[][] rotated = new Pixel[iWidth][iHeight];

    for (int x = 0; x < iWidth; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < iHeight; y++) {
            rotated[x][y] = image[iWidth- y - 1][x];
        }
    }

    image = rotated;

    int temp = iHeight;
    iHeight = iWidth;
    iWidth = temp;
}
```

I would also suggest that you take a look at [java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). It will help a lot in improving the readability of your code.

Comment: For the line for Pixel[][] rotated = new Pixel[iHeight][iWidth];

I actually purposely swapped the position of iHeight and iWidth since the original Image array is Image[iHeight][iWidth].

So when I try your code, this will result to arrayoutofboundsexception

Comment: @user1862452 I was making assumptions since there was no clarity upon this, I changed it for your swapped height and width. Give it a try.

Comment: Are you sure with "rotated[x][y] = image[iWidth- y - 1][x];?" I changed iWidth to iHeight, and It stopped giving a -1 error. It is still outputting the same garbled image unfortunately. :/

Comment: Try it with my code. If you have the code used to display the image we could even see if there is something wrong with it.

Comment: Yes, I tried using your method and my output is the same as mine, although with the exception of iWidth which I replaced with iHeight

Comment: I don't have a viewer, but I write it instead in a file. Here's the code for it http://pastebin.com/W78fbvYS

Comment: Do you have something against `for` loops? :/

Comment: yeh, I find while more readable and flexible. I actually despise it. 
Anyways it's getting off-topic. I just found out that my code and your code is doing a 45 degree read on the original file. 
I tried this sample image: [Original](http://puu.sh/59Mgl.png) vs [Your method](http://puu.sh/59MkQ.png). It's the same output as my code

Answer (score 0):

Throw it all away and use an AffineTransform.